# No ping to local IP from specific local IP only

Tags: networking, router, ftp

I experience a strange problems with my computer which is connected to the internet via Router.

**My PC's IP is**: 192.168.0.12
**FTP where I want to connect:** 192.168.0.15 with username anonymous and no password
**Environment:** Windows 7 x64

I tried to connect to FTP from my laptop on WIFI, everything is perfect, 2.3mbps transfer speed. I tried even from my Android Phone and Android Tablet - no problem.

I restored Router's **factory settings**. I **uninstalled**, and **reinstalled** with the most recent Ethernet drivers for my PC (Asus Rampage IV Extreme Motherboard with built-in Ethernet/LAN) to drop all configurations for this network card which I didn't changed a bit (just in case). I have **no problem to connect to another FTPs** (webservers, hosting domains, etc...).

The problem occurs only for the local IP `192.168.0.15`

Any help pls ? If someone could provide a guidelines where I can find out the problem, it would be nice

**==== UPDATED ====**

Wireshark screenshot while doing `ping 192.168.0.15`

[image]

Comment: Try FTP 192.168.0.15 with Wireshark running.

Comment: Since the Wireshark trace shows no response from 192.168.0.15, FTP will not work for sure.

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.0.12 from 192.168.0.15?

Comment: Guys, thank you for your answers, the problem was in Router, as was said by my Internet provider. I don't know what was the exact problem, but they said it got damaged somehow. Got it replaced and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following things:

1. is the subnet mask on both Computers set correct? is there any IP address conflict in your network such as two computers having the same IP address?
2. is one of your computer using redundant network connections? If so, deactivate it temporary to see if things get better.
3. use Wireshark on both computers to check whether the IP packets are transmitted and received correctly.
4. although not very possible: does your router Support VLAN so that the both computers are separated?

Comment: 1. It's automatically configured. It worked before, nothing was changed there (at least I am only one user on this computer and I did not changed anything).
2. Nope, only one network adapter is available, no wifi, only Ethernet.
3. I will try to learn to find out how to work with it. THANKS
4. I don't know, probably not, both machines have an access to internet.

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot from Wireshark, pls check it out

Comment: step 3 will give you invaluable information. It will tell you 1) is the ping request properly received on the other end and 2) if it is received, is the client properly responding to the request.

This narrows down specifically where communication is breaking down. Since you're on a small network, it probably will be either the client or the router, this step will tell you which one. The update you added is insufficient as all it tells us is that the host sending the request does not get a reply, there is no indication as to why.

Next time you do this, watch interfaces on both sides.

Comment: The second message shows the MAC address of the network adapter that has 192.168.0.15. Please check if it is the same MAC of the Computer that hosts the FTP server. Also, please run wireshark on both computers to check if the packets arrived.